# I can't reference the object I've instantiated

Tags: java, object, reference

I'm trying to reference the GPA in my StudentData class, however I'm getting an error that says it can't find the symbol on the line that says aStudent.gpa = studentGPA.

my main class:

```
public static void main (String [] args)
{

//local constants
final String QUIT = "Quit";
final String YES = "Y";
final int MODIFY_GPA = 1;
final int DISPLAY_USER = 2;
final int QUIT_MENU = 3;

//local variables
String name;            //name of the user
String idPrompt;        //asks the user if they want to input a gpa and id
String studentID;       //student ID input by the user
float studentGPA;       //student GPA input by the user
int choice;     //prompts the user for a menu choice

Library myLib = new Library();
/******************  Start main method *******************/



//prompt for name of user or quit
System.out.print("Enter name of user(First and Last, Quit to end):  ");
name = Keyboard.readString();

      while(!QUIT.equals(name))
      {
          //ask the user if they want to enter ID and GPA
          System.out.print("Do you want to enter an ID and GPA?(Y/N): ");
          idPrompt = Keyboard.readString();

          //if the user says yes
          if(!YES.equals(idPrompt))
          {
              //instantiate a new Student with just the name
              StudentData aStudent = new StudentData(name, "", 0);
          }
          else
          {
              //prompt the user for the ID
              System.out.print("Enter the  Student ID:  ");
              studentID = Keyboard.readString();

              //prompt the user for the GPA
              System.out.print("Enter the Student GPA:  ");
              studentGPA = Keyboard.readFloat();

              //instantiate a new Student with all three data types
              StudentData aStudent = new StudentData(name, studentID, studentGPA);
          }

          //clear the screen
          myLib.clrscr();

          //prompt user for a menu choice
          choice = displayMenu();

          //clear the screen
          myLib.clrscr();

          //begin while loop to modify the user or display
          while(choice != QUIT_MENU)
          {
              //if the user wants to modify the GPA
              if(choice == MODIFY_GPA)
              {
                  studentGPA = StudentData.modifyGPA();
                  aStudent.gpa = studentGPA;
              }
              //if the user wants to display
              else if(choice == DISPLAY_USER)
              {
                  System.out.print("STUDENT OUTPUT");
                  //System.out.println(StudentData);
              }
              //if there was an invalid menu choice
              else
              {
                  System.out.print("INVALID DATA ENTERED");
              }

              //prompt for next choice
              choice = displayMenu();
          }

          //prompt for name of user or quit
          System.out.print("Enter name of user(First and Last, Quit to end):  ");
          name = Keyboard.readString();

      }
  }//end main method
```

and this is my StudentData class
    public class StudentData
    {
    public String name;
    public String id;
    public float gpa;

```
//create a constructor that will receive the name of the student only
public StudentData(String inName)
{
   //local variables
   id = "";             //set the ID to null
   gpa = 0.00F;         //set the gpa to 0.00
   name = inName;       //gets the name of the student from the user
}

//create an overloaded constructor that will receive all three pieces of instance data
public StudentData(String inName, String inID, float inGPA)
{
   name = inName;       //name input by user through the constructor parameter
   id = inID;           //ID input by user through the constructor parameter
   gpa = inGPA;         //GPA input by user through constructor parameter
}

//create a method that will modify the students GPA
public static float modifyGPA()
{
   //local constants
   //local variables
   float newGPA;

   System.out.print("Enter new GPA:  ");
   newGPA = Keyboard.readFloat();

   return newGPA;
}

//create a toString method that will format the instance data to look like:
public String toString()
{
   String format;

   format = ("Student" + name + "\n" +
             "Student ID" + id + "\n" +
             "Student GPA" + gpa + "\n");

   return format;
}
```

Comment: @Makoto: that's not really needed. It's all about declaring a variable in a local block, limiting its scope.

Answer (score 2):

It's the `studentGPA` variable. It's declared in a local block:

```
if(!YES.equals(idPrompt))
{
   // variable *declared* here!
   StudentData aStudent = new StudentData(name, "", 0); 
       // aStudent is visible here
}
// but it's not visible here out of the scope of this local block.
```

and thus only visible in that block. If you want it visible throughout the method, then declare it in method or class scope.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I ended up instantiating the object outside of the If statement. It'd be helpful if my teacher ever explained these kinds of things!

Comment: @user3335456: your teacher can't explain everything as there's too much to explain and learn. You actually learn a lot of this by stumbling over these kinds of mistakes. Mistakes made = knowledge gained.

Comment: Very true. It seems very obvious now that I've had some help. Thanks for the push in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Scope, scope, scope!!  Declarations in Java (and C/C++) are "scoped" to the "block", where a "block" is a set of statements between `{` and `}`.

This means that if you declare a variable `{ StudentData aStudent = new StudentData(...); }` it goes "poof" when you pass that closing `}`.  If you want it to be "visible" outside that scope you need to declare `aStudent` outside the block.

Note that you can still do the assignment *inside* that block, just don't mistakenly include `StudentData` or you will be declaring an entirely different version of the variable.  And note that, in Java, a variable must be assigned a value along all possible paths from its declaration to its use, so you may have to assign `null` (eg) to the variable where it's declared.

Answer (score 0):

for your posted problem,you can do like this in main class,

```
  // your code

  StudentData aStudent = null;

  while(!QUIT.equals(name))
  {
      //your code

      //if the user says yes
      if(!YES.equals(idPrompt))
      {
          //instantiate a new Student with just the name
           aStudent = new StudentData(name, "", 0);
      }
      else
      {
          //your code

          //instantiate a new Student with all three data types
          aStudent = new StudentData(name, studentID, studentGPA);
      }

    //your code
```